# Linux Virtual Console bottom cut off

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, virtual-console

The bottom few lines are cut off in the Linux virtual console. I have switched around from nvidia drivers to the x-org servers and back, no luck. Interestingly, this issue occurs when booting from any linux partition on the computer, Ubuntu and Mint distros.

Running the setupcon command fixes it, but if I switch to GUI and back to the virtual console, the issue comes back.

Comment: You're not using a CRT monitor, by chance, are you?

Comment: nope, standard LCD netbook monitor